# What does () mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've found a Scala code snippet which declares a method `<init>` and puts `()` right below the invocation.

I have a question about line number 5. What does `()` mean here?

```
(() => {
  final class $anon extends MutableProjection {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    ...
  };
  new $anon()
})
```

Here is a [code](https://gist.github.com/marmbrus/9efb31d2b5154aea6652) with full example.

Comment: Any ideas why we need to invoke it? What is the point of such action?

Comment: The code in your question, and the code you link to, **is not legal Scala code**. It's an intermediate language used inside the Scala compiler. It is certainly Scala-like, but if you're trying to understand stuff about Scala by looking at this, you're likely to get very confused.

Answer (score 9):

Every Scala function has a return type. By convention (and highly encouraged by some language features), functions that don't need to return anything have a return type called `Unit`, which has a singleton value written as `()`.

The last expression in a function body is its return value. That author made this be `()` to cause the compiler to infer that the return type should be `Unit`. But it would have been more clear to just do that with a type annotation. If a function's return type is `Unit`, Scala will implicitly return `()` from the function no matter what the last statement in the body is. So this

```
def <init>() = {
  super.<init>()
  ()
}
```

could be written equivalently as

```
def <init>(): Unit = super.<init>()
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the best practice: to specify return type (`: Unit`) or just return `()`?

Comment: I hesitate to declare a "best practice" without any citation, but I can't think of any reason to prefer explicitly including the `()` value. The example you linked looks like generated code or something, so I wouldn't go by that.

Comment: "this singleton value called Unit, which can also be written as () for brevity" `Unit` is the name of the type only, the value can only be written as `()`. The `Unit` _value_ is the companion object of this type.

Comment: Ah, I thought the companion was the instance. Fixing my answer.

Comment: @user3552363 The type can be written either way, the value cannot.

Comment: Every literal is a value.

Comment: @user3552363 In what Scala version? I get `'=>' expected but '=' found` http://scastie.org/12274.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov 2.11.7. Oh, I see. It does not compile. The right expression is `def fun(): Unit = {}`. My IDE is not able to find it out on the fly. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

`()` can meean a few things, depending on context.

As a value, it is an empty tuple, or the singleton type. It's type is `Unit`.

It can denote a function or method that takes no parameters, such as:

```
def foo() = "Hello world"
```

Note that when writing an anonymous function, the `()` is by itself but still means a function with no parameters.

```
val x = () => 2
```

The type of `x` is `() => Int`, a function taking no parameters and returning an int.

As a source of infinite confusion, you can get examples like this:

```
val y = () => ()
```

The type of `y` here is `() => Unit`, a function of no parameters returning `Unit`, not `Unit => Unit`, which would be writen as `val z = (x:Unit) => ()`, and called like `z(())`

The unit vs empty parameter distinction has been awkward for me in the past so hopefully that demystifies some of it.

Comment: `(x:Unit) => ()`... kind of perversion :)